# Create a $9$ degree polynomial equation with integer coefficient that has no rational root but has exactly $5$ real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was able to generate a few polynomials that had $5$ real roots and none are rational by using for example multiples of pi
$f(x)=(x-\pi)(x-2\pi)(x-3\pi)(x-4\pi)(x-5\pi)(x^2+1)(x^2+4)$

Yet every time I play with other examples I can't get integer coefficients. Is there a simpler way to generate what I want other then trial and error?

Comment: You can use algebraic numbers...

Comment: You have to use algebraic irrational numbers. If you use $\pi$, it cannot be a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not all too difficult. First we think of a degree $5$ polynomial with just one real irrational root, and then we make up two quadratic polynomials with two real irrational roots each. Here is the result:
$$p(x):=(x^5-3)(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)\ .$$

Comment: Now this answer is definitely easier than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Forget $\pi$. Use any computer algebra system (or Cardano's formula directly, if you love troubles) to find any 3rd degree polynomial with integer coefficients and with three irrational real roots. I guess $x^3-3x-1$ would do. Then multiply it by any quadratic polynomial with two irrational real roots ($x^2-2$ would do). Then throw in something with no real roots at all ($x^2+1$ would do). That would be it.

Comment: Or Eisenstein's criterion, or just $5(x-1)x(x+1)+1$ and the rational root theorem. There are easier ways than CAS or Cardano.

Comment: They are easier for polynomials of sufficiently high degree, but hardly here.

Comment: I think they are, because they don't require you to calculate nested cube roots as part of a trial-and-error process. Trying, say, five candidates is faster with both Eisenstein (where you have to check the discriminant that the are really three real roots) and with rational root theorem (where you have to evaluate a polynomial at four points). But whatever.

Comment: True, but I didn't have to try as many as five candidates. ;-)